Ising Model Simulation Increase Efficiency
I implemented a 2d simulation of Ising Model for zero external magnetic field. Below you can find the function I wrote to calculate the energy (periodic conditions)
energyMicrostate[state_] :=  Module[{neighborSum},  neighborSum =  ListCorrelate[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, state, {2, 2},  "Periodic", Times];- Total[\[Epsilon] ArrayFlatten[state]*neighborSum, 2]/2]
I consider a Monte Carlo simulation, and hence the microstate is updated accordingly through the functions
changeEnergyMicrostate[state_, flippedsite_] := 
 Module[{x = flippedsite[[1]], y = flippedsite[[2]]},
  Module[{changeenergy = 2 \[Epsilon] state[[x,y]]*(state[[Mod[x - 2, n] + 1, y]] + 
        state[[x, Mod[y - 2, n] + 1]] + state[[Mod[x, n] + 1, y]] + 
        state[[x, Mod[y, n] + 1]])}, changeenergy]]


updateFunction[state_, T_] := 
 Module[{p = RandomReal[], x = RandomInteger[{1, n}], 
   y = RandomInteger[{1, n}], newstate}, 
  Module[{\[CapitalDelta]energy = 
     changeEnergyMicrostate[state, {x, y}]}, 
   If[p < E^(-\[CapitalDelta]energy/T), newstate = state;
    newstate[[x, 
      y]] = -newstate[[x, 
       y]]; {newstate, \[CapitalDelta]energy} , {state, 0}]]]

Finally, the Monte Carlo simulation to find the average energy and heat capacity is implemented as follows:
monteCarloSimulationEandC[initialstate_, T_, iterations_] := 
 Module[{energyinitial = 
    energyMicrostate[initialstate]}, 
  Module[{listenergies = 
     SparseArray[#[[2]] & /@ 
       NestList[
        updateFunction[#[[1]], T] &, {initialstate, energyinitial}, 
        iterations]]}, 
   Module[{mean = N@Mean[Accumulate[listenergies][[1000 ;;]]], 
     meansquared = 
      N@Mean[Accumulate[listenergies][[1000 ;;]]^2]}, {mean, 
     N@(1/T^2) (meansquared - mean^2)}]]]

My question is how can these code be optimised for 10^7 iterations? It takes me around 5 minutes to run for 10^6 but for 10^7 then it would take at least 10 times longer. Is Mathematica the right tool for this? I suspect there is simply a limit on the memory allocation which stops me from further optimising the code.
Thanks.

Mathematica, or any high level language for that matter, is not the right tool for this. For such simulations, consider a low-level language like C++. My LTemplate package has an example of an Ising model simulation written in C++ that integrates with Mathematica. https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate

Alternatively, you can try to use Compile. But in order for it to work efficiently, it will be necessary to restrict the programming constructs you use, and change the programming style. In the end it'll end up looking much like C.

I fully second what Szabolcs says.

Thank you for your comments. I agree better implementations may be done in low level languages, but nevertheless do you think my code could be further optimised?
